# R Shiny input$map_click from observeEvent to create polygon output NULL until clicked

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet-r

I have a code to calculate distance isochrones. Two inputs needed are starting location (lon,lat) and distance. My goal is to have the user select price input using slider input (which then outputs distance based on saved dataframe "ranges" or "ranges2") and then select a point on the map by clicking somewhere and then plug that into the isochrone function that I embedded in addPolygons.

The only reason this is failing is b/c the lat/lon are NULL before the user clicks on the map. How can I make the function wait to calculate a polygon until the user clicks on the map? Or how can I start with initial value and then change polygons once the user makes a selection. Also, I want the polygons to clear each time the user either changes the slider input or selects a different point.

One thing to note is that if I move the addPolygons() call that's currently in output$map to observeEvent leafletProxy(), I do not get the NULL error, but the issue with having it there is that the sliderInput doesn't change until I click on another point.

Thanks so much!

Here is my code:

```
library(sf)         # simple features package - vector
library(leaflet)    # interactive maps
library(osrm)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)


ranges <- read_csv('Isochrone_ranges.csv')
head(ranges)

ranges2 <- read_csv('Isochrone_ranges2.csv')
head(ranges2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position = 'left',
                sidebarPanel(width=3,
                             sliderInput('Price','Delivered Price', 39, max(ranges$Price),
                                         value = 55, step = 1),
                             br(),
                             tags$small(paste0(
                               "Note: Delivered price includes the cost of biomass harvesting/collection and transportation costs. We used $38/BDT in this simulation,",
                               " representing an average of high (e.g., from National Forests) and low (e.g., from industrial timberlands) collection costs", 
                               " found in the literature for our study region."))
                             
                ),
                
                mainPanel(
                  fluidRow(
                    column(5,leafletOutput('map',width='900px',height='800px')),
                  )
                )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dat <- reactive({
    ranges$Distance_Diesel[ranges$Price == input$Price]
  })
  
  dat2 <- reactive({
    ranges2$Distance_Electric[ranges$Price == input$Price]
  })
  
  map_click <- reactive({
    input$map_click
  })
  
  df <- data.frame(lng=-121.44,lat=37.5)
  
  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    print(c(map_click()[[1]],map_click()[[2]]))
    if(is.null(map_click()))
      return()
    text<-paste0('Diesel: ',ranges$Distance_Diesel[ranges$Price == input$Price],
                 '<br>Electric: ',ranges2$Distance_Electric[ranges$Price == input$Price])
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearPopups() %>%
      addPopups(map_click()[[2]], map_click()[[1]], text)
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      fitBounds(-124.82,32.52884,-114.1312,42.00951) %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.NatGeoWorldMap", group="Greyscale") %>%
      addPolygons(data = osrmIsodistance(c(map_click()[[2]],map_click()[[1]]),
                                         breaks=c(dat(),dat2()),
                                         res=20, osrm.server=getOption("osrm.server"),
                                         osrm.profile=getOption("osrm.profile")),
                  fillColor=c('orange','purple'),opacity=1,color='black',weight=1)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```